# Sparkling water droplet project running issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, h2o

I cloned sparkling droplet project from 'https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-droplets/tree/master/sparkling-water-droplet'. And cleaned and build project using **./gradlew clean** ,  **./gradlew build** respectively. After  that tried to run project using command
**spark-submit --class water.droplets.SparklingWaterDroplet build/libs/sparkling-water-droplet-app.jar**
Then got following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: water/fvec/Frame
at water.droplets.SparklingWaterDroplet.main(SparklingWaterDroplet.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: water.fvec.Frame
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 10 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run `./gradlew shadowJar` and use the jar created by it `build/libs/sparkling-water-droplet-app.jar` instead since it creates a fat jar which contains all classes required while submitting a job (the `build` task does not do that).

Comment: Additional note: i pushed upgrade of droplet to be in sync with the latest release of Sparkling Water

Comment: I did the showJar step. The complaint is not about the water/fvec/Frame classes, but about missing org/apache/spark/repl/h2o/H2OInterpreter

I checked, the class sits in a SparklingWater jar sparkling-water-repl_2.10-1.6.4.jar

which is declared as a dependency, but ./gradlew shadowJar did not include it in the fat jar.

Anyone knows why not?

Comment: @bhomass I have the same issue as your. Did you have solved it?